# Redirect after script was executed

Tags: angularjs, redirect, ionic-framework

I am really new in webprogramming and using angularJs and ionic to create an app.

Here is my problem, morelikeley my issue that I want to deal with the right way:
I have got a button which will exchange some data with my server and then link to an other website.
I am now wondering if it is the correct way to add an ng-clicked on my button which then runs a script that talks to my server and after that calls the next website by $location.path()?

```
Problem with this is, that it always throws an error saying: 
Error: $location is not defined $scope.click@http://localhost:8100/scripts/controllers.js:17:9 $parseFunctionCall@http://localhost:8100/lib/angular/angular.js:12237:15 @http://localhost:8100>/lib/ionic/release/js/ionic-angular.js:7788:9 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:8100/lib/angular/angular.js:14291:16 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8100/lib/angular/angular.js:14389:18 @http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/release/js/ionic-angular.js:7787:7 jQuery.event.dispatch@http://localhost:8100/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4408:15 jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle@http://localhost:8100/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4095:6 triggerMouseEvent@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/release/js/ionic.js:2641:3 tapClick@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/release/js/ionic.js:2630:3 tapMouseUp@http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/release/js/ionic.js:2700:5
```

My other idea is to set an href on the button which links to the next website, but then i cannot ensure that my script was executed successfully before redirecting, or is there a way to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: $location is not defined probably means that you dont inject the location service

Comment: What Avraam said. Also, if you are making an $http request to your server then you can use the .success() async method to then call $location.path(...)

    `$http.get({...}).success(function() { $location.path(...)});`

Comment: So, how do i inect the location service?

Comment: angular.serviceORcontroller('name', function($location) {})